# How to create a volume from snapshot openstack using connection in python?

Tags: python, connection, openstack, snapshot, volumes

I am trying to create a volume from a snapshot in openstack using the python api. Using the UI this is easily doable by pressing the action `Create Volume` in the snapshot overview.

When looking at the python documentation though, I can't find the required method. I found `create_volume_snapshot` which creates the snapshot, but I am unable to find a method that creates a volume from a snapshot. I also found the parameter where you can handover an image to create a volume, but nothing for snapshot. I must be blind.

This is the documentation:
https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to create a volume from snapshot using only connection. However, one can use the cinderclient (python api) for it. A minimal example would be:

```
from keystoneauth1 import loading
from keystoneauth1 import session
from cinderclient import client
def create_cinder(self, version=3):
    loader = loading.get_plugin_loader('password')
    auth = loader.load_from_options(auth_url=os.environ["OS_AUTH_URL"],
                                    username=os.environ["OS_USERNAME"],
                                    password=os.environ["OS_PASSWORD"],
                                    project_id=os.environ["OS_PROJECT_ID"],
                                    user_domain_name=os.environ["OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"])
    sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
    return client.Client(version, session=sess)
cinder = create_cinder()
cinder.volumes.create(size="size", snapshot_id="id", name="name",
                                           description="description")
```

This example only works if you enter possible values for size id name and description and set the environment variables correctly.